# How can i turn a local website (directory on my PC) stored in a filder into a .webarchive file?

Tags: ipad, webarchive

I have a full website html, css, images, javascripts and video on my local hardrive all contained in a folder.

the website works great on my PC but i need to transfer it to an iPad, i was thinking that this should be easy ... well its not since i cant just copy the site over and run it like on my PC.

so my next step was to try and make a .webarchive of the site but since it has a lot of jquery and video files i cant just use safari since it wont include any of the video files and so on.

was hoping someone knows of a tool or a method to convert a folder into a webarchive.

Answer (score 0):

Just open the website over safari and then Save As... web archive.
My currently unsolved issue is exactly the reverse one.

Comment: i have tried that however since there are video files that are loaded via jquery safari does not save those video files in the archive